# Why is plt.savefig not saving any file at all?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I seem to be having a strange situation wherein `plt.savefig` seems not to save any file at all.

The code is of the form of

```
df.plot().legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.savefig(label + "_" + "Plot_Type_Name.png", bbox_inches="tight")
plt.close("all")
```

and it is being run from a command-line and/or from PyCharm.
It's not apparent to me why it's failing. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Check your working directory...

Answer (score 2):

The code from the question *will* save a figure under the condition that `df` is defined and `df.plot()` creates a plot. Here is a full working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"x":np.arange(5),"y":np.random.rand(5)})

df.plot().legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

fname="label.png"
plt.savefig(fname, bbox_inches="tight")
plt.close("all")
```

You may test that the file is actually there

```
import os
if os.path.exists(fname):
    print(os.path.abspath(fname))
else:
    print("file not found")
```

Comment: You're correct, this works for me. Thanks for the comment above, I deleted my wrong answer.

Comment: The problem seems to have gone; I'm not sure if it was about the files being overwritten or something. I learned from your test regarding the file's presence, though, so I've attempted an upvote of your answer. (My reputation isn't yet high enough for my upvotes to be counted.) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`savefig()` needs to be before `show()`